# How do i validate a variable being an integer and within a certain range

Tags: python, validation, integer, range

```
Find = input("What estimate number? ")
```

I want it to loop back if they enter a non integer and also if they entered a number that is below 1 and above 190
This is going to be within a subprogram

Answer (score -2):

```
try:
if 1 <= int(Find) <= 190:
  // good
else:
  // prompt again
except ValueError as e:
  // not integer
```

Comment: What happens if `Find` is not an integer?

Comment: Yes, my bad, edited

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.